# Xcode - installing cocoapods

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to install cocoapods on my MacBook Pro which is running OSX Mavericks and version 5.02 of Xcode and get the following error when I run the sudo gem install cocoapods:

> ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0), here is why:
>             Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - Errno::ENOMEM: Cannot allocate memory - connect(2)
>   (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

I have a MacBook Pro with 256G SSD and 8G ram.

Comment: seems like a problem with ruby. Please take a look in the guide:
http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#getting-started

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cocoapods with Xcode 6 and 10.10 Yosemite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018355/cocoapods-with-xcode-6-and-10-10-yosemite)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to lack of proper Xcode Command Line Tools. Visit https://developer.apple.com/downloads/ and install the latest Command Line Tools that match your Mac OS and Xcode version. Then try running:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```