# Cocoapods with Xcode 6 and 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, osx-yosemite, osx-yosemite-beta

After initially upgrading to 10.10 and XCode6-Beta, I tried to run 'pod update' and I received this error:

```
cannot load such file -- xcodeproj/prebuilt/universal.x86_64-darwin14-2.0.0/xcodeproj_ext (LoadError)
```

I tried to update Cocoapods using 'sudo gem install cocoapods', but received another error:

```
Fetching: xcodeproj-0.17.0.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

"/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby" -rubygems /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake RUBYARCHDIR=/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.17.0/ext RUBYLIBDIR=/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.17.0/ext
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for -std=c99 option to compiler... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.
```

Has anyone else been able to successfully use Cocoapods with Xcode 6 on 10.10 Yosemite?

Comment: Related for people using XCode 5 and want to release their app updates to ITMS now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24728019/cocoapods-with-xcode-5-and-10-10-yosemite

Answer (score 185, accepted):

1. Open Xcode 6
2. Open Preferences
3. Click the Locations tab
4. Change the `Command Line Tools` version to `Xcode 6.0`
5. Uninstall cocoapods
   `$ sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`
6. Uninstall xcodeproj
   `$ sudo gem uninstall xcodeproj`
7. Install xcodeproj
   `$ sudo gem install xcodeproj`
8. Install cocoapods
   `$ sudo gem install cocoapods`
9. Run `pod --version` to verify that it worked

Comment: If you get this error in step 7, try again: `SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read finished A`. Worked for me the second time.

Comment: What was the problem of earlier version ?

Comment: I had to perform an extra step between steps 5 and 6 for it to work for me, that is uninstall xcodeproj: `$ sudo gem uninstall xcodeproj`. Other than that, it's perfect.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I continue to get the following error: http://pastie.org/private/8xkha1gdbxcbvdldkxtkaw. Any ideas of why this may be?

Comment: Same here.  Getting the same exact error as Rasmus.  In my case it used to work, however I just upgraded to Xcode6b7.  Anyone have a workaround?

Comment: @RasmusTaulborgHummelmose I was getting that, used johnyorke's answer, reinstalling ruby via homebrew then all was fine...

Comment: I was still getting a ruby compile error when installing the cocoapods gem. As mentioned below, this is due to the fact that Xcode 6.0.1 (GA) doesn't have the 10.10 SDK (since it isn't GA yet). I don't have Mac App development SDK access to get the Xcode 6.1 beta, so I simply downloaded and installed the "Command Line Tools (OS X 10.10) for Xcode - September 2014" from the developer downloads site and did the above again, and it worked.  Link: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode#  Good luck!

Comment: It did not work for me, but worked after running the following command, $ gem update --system
$ gem install rubygems-update
$ update_rubygems

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me after getting this error: /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'cocoapods' (>= 0) among 21 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)

Comment: While installing using **-V** as parameter prints everything what the installer does to the screen. So you see what's happening. I restarted a few times, because I thought that nothing happened.

Answer (score 35):

// Running Xcode6-Beta7 on 10.10 (14A343f)

I have tried all of the above and didn't have any luck. Here's what worked for me:

I installed the latest version of Ruby via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) (took a few minutes)

```
brew install ruby
```

then installed Cocoapods as usual

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

and it worked a treat!

Comment: Thank you! Worked for me on Xcode 6.1 beta (6A1030)

Comment: I had to follow this guide as well: [Brew fix](http://jcvangent.com/fixing-homebrew-os-x-10-10-yosemite/)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to uninstalling cocoapods and installing xcodeproj gems.  I also had to tell rvm to use the system ruby.  Strange because my rvm install was 2.0.0 as was the system version after switching to use 6.0.0 Command Line Tools

```
rvm use system    
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install xcodeproj
sudo gem install cocoapods
pod install
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, looks like it's been reported and has a workaround:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2219

The following worked for me:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install xcodeproj
sudo gem install cocoapods
pod update
```

Comment: If I do that sequence, I still get the same `xcodeproj` install error you mentioned above. Can you provide any more details about your config?

Comment: It looks like the relevant log file (mkmf.log) was overwritten, sorry!  Do you have a specific question about my config?  Also, have you tried 'sudo gem uninstall xcodeproj'?

Comment: I ended up getting it to work, posted my solution on the github repo:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2219#issuecomment-44979127

Comment: I had more than one xcodeproj gem installed before this. Make sure you uninstall all your xcodeproj gems as well before re-installing both.

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

/usr/bin/login -f     your_mac_username

cd "to your project"

pod install

Done.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 6.0 GM is missing the 10.10 SDK and therefore the gem `xcodeproj` can't be compiled which has some C code in it which needs the 10.10 SDK.
This is going to be fixed in the future.
For now you can work around it like this (**no** need for `rvm` or anything else):

- Terminal: `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods xcodeproj`
- Download Xcode 6.1 (right now Beta 2 is the current one)
- Start it go to Settings -> Location -> Command Line Tools -> Change to Xcode 6.1 Beta
- Terminal: `sudo gem install cocoapods`
- Change your Command Line tools back to GM (if you want/need)

For more information see: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2432

Answer (score 1):

We released CocoaPods 0.34 which no longer has any C based extensions and will install without even installing Xcode, thus should be able to work around this tough setup that Apple gave us all.

Answer (score 1):

i found this solution in this [link](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2432)

`$sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode6-Beta7.app /Applications/Xcode.app
$sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.Internal.sdk
$ sudo gem install cocoapods`

once the installation done, you can delete the links like so :

`$ rm /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.Internal.sdk
$ rm /Applications/Xcode.app`

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out that simply deleting ~/.rvm folder resolves whatever problems arise from version, ACL, and configuration conflicts. All your gems will have to be reinstalled but this is the simplest solution I've found. You can continue using Xcode 5 (no switch required). So simply run

```
> sudo rm -rf ~/.rvm
```

in shell.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the steps in Kyle Robson answer. The update to Yosemite Dev Preview 8 resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by re-downloading the latest version of the Command Line Tools for 10.10

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install cocoapods
$ pod repo remove master
$ pod setup
$ pod install
```