# Cocoapods with Xcode 5 and 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: xcode, xcode5, cocoapods, osx-yosemite, osx-yosemite-beta

After initially upgrading to 10.10 and XCode6-Beta, I tried to run 'pod update' and I received this error:

```
cannot load such file -- xcodeproj/prebuilt/universal.x86_64-darwin14-2.0.0/xcodeproj_ext (LoadError)
```

I tried to update Cocoapods using 'sudo gem install cocoapods', but received another error:

```
Fetching: xcodeproj-0.17.0.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

"/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby" -rubygems /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.1.1/bin/rake RUBYARCHDIR=/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.17.0/ext RUBYLIBDIR=/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.17.0/ext
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for -std=c99 option to compiler... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.
```

Even though I have installed XCode 6, I would like to use XCode 5 at this time because I want to make releases.

Related: [Cocoapods with Xcode 6 and 10.10 Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018355/cocoapods-with-xcode-6-and-10-10-yosemite)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to reinstall the cocoapod gem and use XCode6's Command Line Tools, as specified by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24022051/2426994) answer.
Then you can do a pod install and continue to use XCode5.
Just open the xcworkspace created in XCode5 instead of XCode6Beta.

Answer (score 0):

Simply deleting ~/.rvm folder resolves the problems that arise from ruby/library version, ACL, and configuration conflicts. All your gems will have to be reinstalled but this is the simplest and cleanest solution I know of that works with Xcode 5. Just run

```
> sudo rm -rf ~/.rvm
```

in s.hell.