# Cocoapods os x 10.10

Tags: macos, cocoapods, osx-yosemite

I've installed cocoapods like [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018355/cocoapods-with-xcode-6-and-10-10-yosemite)

```
alex-z:~ alex-z$ /usr/bin/gem list --local | grep "cocoapods"
```

Result is empty

```
alex-z:~ alex-z$ sudo !!
```

Result is

```
cocoapods (0.33.1)
cocoapods-core (0.33.1)
cocoapods-downloader (0.6.1)
cocoapods-plugins (0.2.0)
cocoapods-trunk (0.1.4)
cocoapods-try (0.3.0)
```

And next

```
alex-z:~ alex-z$ /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/gem list --local | grep "cocoapods"
alex-z:~ alex-z$ sudo !!
```

Results are the same with results of previous commands

When I try to use `pod` I get error

```
alex-z:~ alex-z$ pod --version
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'cocoapods' (>= 0) among 87 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
```

Has anyone else solved this issue?

Comment: Not sure what's going on here but you may try installing ruby with [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) or [rvm](http://rvm.io/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had different versions of ruby in /usr/bin/ruby (2.0.0-p195) and /System/Library/Frameworks/.../ruby (2.0.0-p481). `rvm upgrade 2.0.0-p195 2.0.0-p481` has helped me.

Comment: use `rvm list known` to list all installable versions of ruby

Comment: also try: `gem install cocoapods`