# Xcode 6 doesn´t find cocoapods libraries

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6, cocoapods

I am trying to build a Xcode 5 project that uses CocoaPods. The POD file is following:

```
target "MyProjectName" do

pod 'AFNetworking', '2.2.1'
pod 'SVProgressHUD', '0.9'
pod 'MDHTMLLabel', :head
pod 'CCBottomRefreshControl'
pod 'EXPhotoViewer', '~> 1.1.2'
pod 'NHBalancedFlowLayout', '~> 0.2'
pod 'SevenSwitch', '~> 1.3.0'
pod 'REFormattedNumberField', '~> 1.1.5'

end
```

The cocoapods is installing and updating correctly.

The error is: Did not find the libraries, like the one highlighted in my .pch:

```
#import "SVProgressHud.h"
...
/Users/xyz/Documents/Projects/avbc/repo/ios/project/ProjectName-Prefix.pch:17:13: 'SVProgressHud.h' file not found
```

I already did the pod reinstalling steps from solution below, without success:
[Cocoapods with Xcode 6 and 10.10 Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018355/cocoapods-with-xcode-6-and-10-10-yosemite)

What should I do to build my project properly?

Comment: Have you added '$(inherited)' as part of your header search paths in each target?

Comment: @JasperBlues How can I do that?

Comment: @JasperBlues I just added '$(inherited)' in each one of my targets header search paths, without success.

Comment: Ok it's not that then. Let's wait for someone more knowledgable.

Comment: @JasperBlues Acctually, I repeated your step and fixed the problem. We need to Clean Project after make target changes to be sure all will be handled in right way.

Comment: Marcel, feel free to add an answer for future users having the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perfom "Project Clean" (Cmd+Shift+K) to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1) I usually set the platform on my pod file:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
```

2) Have you linked the library with <>?:

```
#import <SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD.h>
```

3) It is HUD instead of Hud. (Uppercase) <- If you link to **Hud** the file will never be found