# Cocoapods can't find header xcode 6

Tags: ios, build, xcode6, cocoapods

I have a problem xcode can't find the headers of my pods in my wokspace.

The headers search path for the target seems ok

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ulqqai825a6xrg4/Screenshot%202014-09-29%2010.24.04.png?dl=1]

Here is the content of my podfile

```
target "MyApp" do
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
pod 'Reachability'
pod 'ViewDeck', '2.2.11'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.8'
end
```

But when i build the project i have this error in the prefix.pch

> /Users/...../MyApp-Prefix.pch:17:13: 'AFNetworking.h' file not found

I have tried to add `platform :ios, "8.0"` in my podfile and do a `pod update` but still no luck

I have also tried to add $(inherited) like suggested in the SO question :
[Xcode 6 doesn´t find cocoapods libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25997871/xcode-6-doesn%C2%B4t-find-cocoapods-libraries)

I'm using xcode 6 on mavericks

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

I found solution. In your project properties replace this:

[image: I FOUND SOLUTION]

Comment: FYI, This is in Project Info.

Comment: This worked for me. Seems like whenever I call `pod install`, this is getting resetted or not set correctly. Since I don't use tests in my app (yet), I removed the MyappTests target and voila!

Comment: I am having the same issue, but that solution didn't work for me, I have also set the Header Search Paths appropriately in both targets and set the project settings as above. Any thoughts, so annoying!

Comment: I just want to point out (since I had this same problem), that adding it *for the test target* is what fixed it for me, even though I was trying to build just the regular target. I don't claim to understand why this fixed things, but it worked.

Comment: @shortstuffsushi - Where I can find this file?

Comment: @shortstuffsushi - I got my answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850261/add-cocoapods-to-tests-target-too

Comment: Replace what? What kind of answer is this?!?!

Answer (score 19):

You might also want to link your pods with both your targets like so:

```
platform :osx, '10.7'

link_with 'MyApp', 'MyApp Tests'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 1.0'
pod 'Objection', '0.9'
```

From [Cocoapods docs](http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14906534/how-do-i-specify-multiple-targets-in-my-podfile-for-my-xcode-project)

---

Update: This no longer works for Cocoapods 1.0+, the correct way to implement the Podfile is:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!

target 'MyApp' do
  pod 'ObjectiveSugar', '~> 0.5'

  target "MyAppTests" do
    inherit! :search_paths
    pod 'OCMock', '~> 2.0.1'
  end
end
```

Source: https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#podfile

Comment: I prefer this to removing the tests target.

Comment: link_with  does not work anymore with cocoapods 1.0.1.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to fix this in my project. I had a second target for tests. I never used this target and the error disappeared after I deleted it from the project. So maybe not your main target is the source of the problem, but another one.

Comment: I found the solution using your answer

Comment: Probably better to use @jwswart's answer. Using `link_with` to reference your targets. The test target may prove helpful in the future

Answer (score 0):

I agree with jwswart's answer because quite many times I have realized that the issue with just defining dependencies for the 'MyApp' and leaving out 'MyAppTests' as in:

> target :'MyApp' do
>
> ..
>
> end

breaks the build process because the classes defined in 'MyApp' make use of the dependencies which are not visible in the 'MyAppTests'. Thus as jwswart suggested:

> link_with 'MyApp', 'MyApp Tests'

Answer (score -3):

Just have a try to comment this line for your target

```
#  use_frameworks!
```

~~