# Xcode can't find the main file for the Cocoapod I'm importing despite it being there

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoapods

I'm trying to use [RedditKit](https://github.com/samsymons/RedditKit) to play around with the Reddit API for school, and I'm using Cocoapods despite not being overly familiar.

My Podfile looks like this:

```
platform :ios, '8.4'
link_with 'TestProj', 'TestProjTests'

pod 'RedditKit', "~> 1.3"
```

And I run `pod install` in the same directory with the latest version of Cocoapods (0.39.0). I open the new `.xcworkspace` and when I try to run the project it errors at the line in `RedditKit.h` that says `#import "RKClient.h"` stating:

> 'RKClient.h' file not found

But if I command-click the import statement it brings me to the file, so I know it's there.

What gives? What am I doing wrong here?

I've read other questions such as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002905/ios-build-fails-with-cocoapods-cannot-find-header-files) about ensuring your Configuration uses the pod files, but mine does. I even used the `link_with` suggestion to no avail. Similar thing suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26095775/cocoapods-cant-find-header-xcode-6) and I can't seem to find why it's happening.

What should I be doing? How can I fix this?

Comment: did you explicitly build the Pod target in your workspace?  I've found I sometimes need to do that before a `.h` file included in a Pod gets picked up in my own project's targets.

Comment: hey any luck resolving this? I am stuck in same problem.