# Xcode not searching correct subdirectory for headers

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, header-files

I am using Cocoapods for dependency resolution in an iOS project.

The problem I am having is that the compiler is unable to find the correct subdirectory where the headers are located.

See in the image below the directory in which the compiler is searching for the header file:

[image: /Users/Scott/Documents/GitHub/ios-demo/Pods/iOS-KML-Framework]

However, the file is in the subdirectory `/Users/Scott/Documents/GitHub/ios-demo/Pods/iOS-KML-Framework/KML`. How do I specifically enable that subdirectory to be searched? I have tried suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26095775/cocoapods-cant-find-header-xcode-6) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002905/ios-build-fails-with-cocoapods-cannot-find-header-files?rq=1) but those did not seem to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try set `Header Search Path` or `Library Search Path` in Building Setting:

[image]

Comment: To be specific, I added `"${PODS_ROOT}"` and set it to `recursive` so it would search __all__ subdirectories

Comment: I don't use pods but this worked for me: `$(PROJECT_DIR)`, and set it to recursive.