# iOS libtool: unknown option character `W' in: -Wl,-U,_JSContextGetGlobalObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, libtool-xcode

I have recently updated Xcode 6.1 on Yosemite and followed [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018355/cocoapods-with-xcode-6-and-10-10-yosemite) to fix cocoa pods issue. I have started getting following error.

```
  error:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: unknown option character `W' in: -Wl,-U,_JSContextGetGlobalObject
```

Further investigation on issue, I found that following line is newly generated in Pods xconfig file after Pod update.

```
OTHER_LIBTOOLFLAGS = $(OTHER_LDFLAGS)
```

I have no idea why is that required but removing this line from Pods config fixed the issue. It comes back when I do pod update again. Does anyone know what's this and why it is causing problem?

Comment: It works for me on Xcode 6.2 and the latest cocoa pods but there's another issue: it still doesn't compile for IBDesignables. That's because Xcode 6 changes the behaviour of OTHER_LDFLAGS. See here: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2666. Unfortunately libtool doesn't like the -ObjC flag so it fails.

Comment: I have the same issue. Hs anybody a solution for this?


> Xcode 7