# unable to install cocoapods in OSX 10.10.5 Xcode 7.0

Tags: ruby, macos, xcode7

Trying to install using Terminal.. But gives me the following answer. 
Not sure whats wrong. Tried to install rvm and update the ruby. but not sure where i am wrong.

> curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin14/rbconfig.rb:213:
>   warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777

Help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cocoapods with Xcode 6 and 10.10 Yosemite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018355/cocoapods-with-xcode-6-and-10-10-yosemite)

Answer (score 1):

After going through it. I finally found that, I needed to write protect the usr/local directory. The following code helped me to remove the error.

```
chown -R 'whoami' /usr/local
```

After the command, it was taking so much time to update. So I did an update.

```
sudo gem update --system -V
```

And then finally

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Worked like a charm.