# How to add new framework to existing project using cocoapods?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I have my existing project `QuickGame` where I would like to add frameworks (`SwiftyJSON` and `Alamofire`) using cocoapods. I installed cocoapods and I created a pod file in my app folder, but now, I don't know how this pod file should looks like, to instal this frameworks in my existing project.

Comment: what about .... googling ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cocoapods with Xcode 6 and 10.10 Yosemite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018355/cocoapods-with-xcode-6-and-10-10-yosemite)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pod file should look like this :

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'YOUR_TARGET_NAME' do
pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
pod 'Alamofire',  :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git'
end
```

Then go to the terminal -> cd [your source folder where the pod file is hosted]
-> then do : pod install

let me know if this help you